# Built-in Calculator returns wrong values for cos(x)

Tags: gnome-calculator

[image]I am curious as to why the gnome-calculator seems to calculate cos(pi) wrongly as seen in the picture. I tried to use different rad/deg settings without getting the correct result.

I am curious what the problem is, as the software surely has to be correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the calculation of cos() is using degrees and not radians in your above example.

Using radians: cos(pi) = -1, note: cos(pi / 180) = 0.999848 (what you are seeing)
Using degrees: cos(180) = -1

To change the angle units used, press the menu button in the top-right corner of the window and select Preferences. Trigonometry buttons are visible when in Advanced mode.

Comment: It might be worth noting that this setting is unrelated to the "Radians in Radians" unit conversion settings on the display - perhaps they're what is causing the OP's confusion?

Comment: @steeldriver this was exactly the case. I remembered switching between rad/deg on my TI-calculator back in school, and thought the visible unit conversion settings would do the same